# How to abstract code dealing with collections

Tags: meteor

I have a couple of different views (client code) that I will need to insert/update my collection(s). Instead  of having the duplicate code handling the insert/update, I'd like to pull that out into a separate file whose functions are globally accessible.

I have seen several examples where this was done using the construct Meteor.methods. Don't all Meteor.methods get executed on the server? How does that impact latency compensation? Is there a better way to do this? Or is this currently an acceptable way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd put them in a method, but expose the method to the client. In other words, don't put it in the `server` directory, and don't guard it with an `if (Meteor.isServer)`. I prefer to define all of my collections along with their methods in a `collections` directory which gets loaded by both the client and the server. If the client has a definition for a method, this is known as a stub. Armed with that information, I'd encourage you to re-read the method section of the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_methods). The short version is that because of latency compensation, the code will be run in parallel on both the client and the server. You can verify this by putting a simple `console.log` in the definition (it will print to both the browser console and the command console on invocation). For a more fancy use of stubs you can see [this](http://www.eventedmind.com/posts/meteor-methods) video.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. The documentation makes more sense now.

Answer (score 2):

On my side I use the following structure:

```
/common/collections/[each collection gets a file where it is defined]
/common/models/[each collection gets a model file where the model is defined]
```

That way I can reuse as much code as I can on both client and servers

I use CoffeeScript to create classes but you could do the same in plain Javascript.

My models constructors accept an hash of attributes (the meteor object) and from there it can encapsulate my methods.

*OffTopic #1: As a bonus, my model extends a super object that I name 'MeteorModel' where I put my shared code between models.*

*OffTopic #2: I also put my allow and deny logic in these models so that I can perform arbitrary validations from the client or server side. Very useful so far as I haven't found a better way to simulate an object modification without actually modifying it in plain Meteor.*

I prefer not to work directly with Meteor.Collections and write my code on the side as it is still unclear how Meteor will evolve and I want room to changed my approach when it does.

Comment: Thanks for sharing how you organize your files. Seeing how others setup their projects is helpful.